# subset of a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Define a  set $E$  to be measurable if for any $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ we have $\mu^*(A)\geq \mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\cap E^c)$

If we have $E$ to be measurable ;Is it true that that $F\subset E$ is also so

Comment: Since $\mathbb R$ is measurable, what would be the point of this notion if the answer were "yes"?

Comment: sorry for such a silly question

Comment: Infact there's a theorem stating that every set of positive measure has a non measurable set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is definitely not true.  Here's a simple argument for why:

We say elements of a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ are "measurable", since measures are defined on $\sigma$-algebras.

Every $\sigma$-algebra contains the entire space as a set, so the entire space is always measurable.  If your assertion that subsets of measurable sets are measurable, then every subset of the entire space should also be measurable.  But that means the only $\sigma$-algebra possible is the power set, i.e., the set of all subsets.  And if this were true, there would be no point in defining different $\sigma$-algebras like the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, or the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, since they would all be the same $\sigma$-algebra.  Every subset would be measurable.

So, in short, it's not true that every subset of a measurable set is measurable.

Comment: yes you are right!